# How to invoke a method when using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an assembly which is loaded using Assembly.LoadFrom. This assembly contains several static method, how can I invoke them once the assembly is loaded correctly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ReflectionSandbox
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void TestAPI()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestAPI");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean the assembly contains static classes with static methods in them?

Comment: @Dervall: Why should the class be static?

Comment: @Heinzi: You're right, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
someAssembly.GetType(someName).GetMethod(someName).Invoke(null, someParameters)
```

The `null` is the instance (`this`) argument; it must be null for static methods.

Comment: Either GetType or GetMethod is returning a null-reference. This happens if there's no method/type with the passed name.